# Usage of Django Rest Framework's @api_view decorator and mysterious bug

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I've run into this odd bug where my code ran fine yesterday (via. automated tests) however broke today. Basically, it feels as if the @api_view decorator breaks and fails to apply for a method. **Here's the situation:**

I have a method named 'advance_orders' and it is wrapped as follows:

```py
@api_view(http_method_names=['POST'], hack=True)
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
@check_wallet_token
@disallow_disabled_users
def advance_orders(request):
    # code that is irrelevant for this issue
```

*NOTE:* hack=True is a small addition I made for debugging purposes after I first discovered the bug.

The methods `@check_wallet_token` and `@disallow_disabled_users` are also irrelevant here and I'm 99.99% certain that they are not the source of the bug (since they worked fined yesterday and in/on other methods which are wrapped similarly)

The url mapping to the function is:
`re_path(r'^vendor/orders/advance/$', vendor.advance_orders, name='advance_order'),`

Now, in a certain test I have:

```py
client = RequestsClient()
# absolute_url == http://testserver/wallet/vendor/orders/advance/
# there are some helper methods which generate it...
# the headers are irrelevant honestly
r = client.post(absolute_url, headers=self.headers, data={"order_id": "asdf"})
print(r.text)
self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 400)
self.assertEqual(json.loads(r.text), {"display_message": "Missing order_id (int)."})
```

The test fails and on printing the response text I find:
`{"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}`

Which makes no sense! Unless I'm doing something blatantly wrong, which I'm pretty sure I'm not.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Now here's when I gather more proof. I go into the source code of the DRF installed in my virtual environment and modify two methods to print out extra debugging info.

In views.py I change `views.APIView.dispatch()` as follows:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        `.dispatch()` is pretty much the same as Django's regular dispatch,
        but with extra hooks for startup, finalize, and exception handling.
        """
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request
        self.headers = self.default_response_headers  # deprecate?

        hack = False
        if request.META['PATH_INFO'] == '/wallet/vendor/orders/advance/':
            print("[HACK - views.py] Method identified as advance_order")
            hack = True

        try:
            self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)

            # Get the appropriate handler method
            if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
                handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)
            else:
                print("[HACK - views.py] list of http_method_names associated with the function: {}".format(self.http_method_names))
                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed

            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

        except Exception as exc:
            response = self.handle_exception(exc)
# and so on as usual...
```

The other method I modify is `decorators.api_view()` to:

```py
def api_view(http_method_names=None, exclude_from_schema=False, hack=False):
    """
    Decorator that converts a function-based view into an APIView subclass.
    Takes a list of allowed methods for the view as an argument.
    """
    http_method_names = ['GET'] if (http_method_names is None) else http_method_names

    if hack:
        print("[HACK - decorators.py] Provided http_method_names: {}".format(http_method_names))
# and so on as usual...
```

Now I run my tests using `./manage.py test Wallet.tests.test_api_vendors.API_VendorTestCase --failfast`
and on printing the results we have:

```
[HACK - decorators.py] Provided http_method_names: ['POST']
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
[HACK - views.py] Method identified as advance_order
[HACK - views.py] list of http_method_names associated with the function: ['get', 'options']
{"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_advance_order (Wallet.tests.test_api_vendors.API_VendorTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/CommonShare/Code/DVM/APOGEE/Wallet/tests/test_api_vendors.py", line 231, in test_advance_order
    self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 400)
AssertionError: 405 != 400

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.377s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Which leaves me absolutely stumped since this means that the decorator recognized that I wanted to allow the 'POST' method but then when my view 'advance_order' is executed, 'POST' is not included in the list of allowed method.

So my question is: Is the mistake on my part? If so, how? Else, what can I do to resolve such an issue? (deleting the __pycache__ files did not work).

P.S. apologies for the very verbose question, I just want to be very clear about my issue.

Comment: You should check your urls.py file(s). If you have `django_extensions` installed you can use `show_urls`. My guess is that the request is being routed to the wrong view.

Comment: @schillingt: yup, my urls were clashing; thanks for the tip!